# PyEZ: RPC: Get route info for specific grandchild element

Tags: rpc, juniper, pyez

I want to get wia RPC info like this:

```
> show route output interface ae40.4181 | display xml rpc 
<rpc-reply xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/17.4R2/junos">
    <rpc>
        <get-route-information>
            <output>
                        <interface>ae40.4181</interface>
                    </output>
            </get-route-information>
        </rpc>
        <cli>
            <banner></banner>
        </cli>
    </rpc-reply>
```

How shloud I pass these parameters to `dev.rpc.get_route_information`?

Which are other possible ways to get this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using dev.execute for this case

for example

```
rpc = '''<get-route-information>
            <output><interface>ae40.4181</interface>
                    </output>
            </get-route-information>'''
dev.execute(rpc)
```

let me know if you face any issue

Comment: How can I get the result of the rpc execute, I tried response=dev.execute(rpc) and printed it, but it printed "True"

Comment: Alaa, share the API call you did.

Comment: rpcRequest= '''<rpc><get-system-uptime-information></get-system-uptime-information></rpc>'''  dev.open(normalize=True)
                        response=dev.execute(rpcRequest)

Comment: just try rpcRequest= "<get-system-uptime-information></get-system-uptime-information>" or rpcRequest= "<get-system-uptime-information/>". Dont pass RPC, check https://github.com/Juniper/py-junos-eznc/blob/master/lib/jnpr/junos/device.py#L735-L736